# what will be the sql query code of this "Healthcare" database?

Tags: mysql

[image]

SQL Query:

1. Write a SQL statement to display the SSN & name of patients who are younger than the average of all patients.
2. Write a SQL statement to display the name and age of the oldest patients along with his or her doctor's name.
3. write a SQL statement to display all of the patients who are prescribed with vitamins and below 50 years old.
4. display the name of most experienced heart specialist.

Solution: I have completed these answers of those questions but not sure it's okay or not. Please help me if there is any wrong or need any correction.

1.)

```
select SSN, Name 
from patient 
where age < ( 
      select avg(age) 
      from Patient 
);
```

2.)

```
select patient.name, max(patient.age), patient.DName 
from Patient 
join Doctor 
where patient.primary_DoctorID = Doctor.DoctorID;
```

3.)

```
SELECT Patient.Name, Patient.age 
from Patient 
where patient.age < '50' and Patient.Primary_DoctorID = ( 
      SELECT Prescription.DoctorID 
      from Prescription 
      where Prescription.P_ID = ( 
            select Prescription_Medicine.P_ID 
            FROM Prescription_Medicine 
            where Prescription_Medicine.Tradename = 'Vitamin' )
);
```

Q3 returns

> > subquery returns more than one row

4. `SELECT dname
   FROM doctor
   IN speciality = 'Heart' AND experience = (
   SELECT MAX(doctor.experience) 
   FROM doctor 
   GROUP BY speciality;
   );`

Comment: This isn't a homework solving service. If you've tried something and had a problem and explain ir properly, we're happy to help.

Comment: sir, for being a new member, it's taking few time to keep pace with it. Now, I have edited my asking with my solve and if you would prefer to see, find if any wrong of those code and give the correction, it would be grateful for me.

Comment: You can visually inspect the data to see what your result should be. When you run the queries, do they give you the right or wrong answer?

Comment: Query 1 seems fine.  Query 2 doesn't need the MAX.  Since they only have 1 current age.  (Although in most databases they would simply keep the birthdate, and calculate age from that).  Query 3 might need improvement, an `EXISTS` could be used for it.

Comment: sir, 1st and 2nd are correct but the 3rd one is showing problem by saying "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row". I didn't find where the problem is and in which line, I will use "EXISTS"???

Comment: Can you edit the question and add that error? Then this question will look like what it should have in the first place - you have an actual question (which I might add has many online explanations)

Comment: sir, the question cannot be edited because it has been given by my teacher.                   
                                                                                                                           In the 3rd question, it's now showing "#1242 - subquery returns more than one row" I have tried to solve it but I was undone. I don't know how can I fix this

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place that you copy/paste teachers questions. I'll edit it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your 3rd query to -

```
SELECT Patient.Name, Patient.age 
from Patient 
where patient.age < '50'
and EXISTS ( 
      SELECT Prescription.DoctorID 
      from Prescription 
      where Patient.Primary_DoctorID = Prescription.DoctorID
      and Prescription.P_ID = ( 
            select Prescription_Medicine.P_ID 
            FROM Prescription_Medicine 
            where Prescription_Medicine.Tradename = 'Vitamin' )
);
```

And update your 4th query to -

```
SELECT dname
FROM doctor d
JOIN (SELECT speciality, MAX(doctor.experience) 
      FROM doctor
      GROUP BY speciality) d1 on d.speciality = d1.speciality
WHERE speciality = 'Heart'
```

Answer (score -1):

--USING MS-SQL SERVER FOR THE 4TH QUERY
--YOU CAN ALSO USE WINDOW FUNCTION TO SOLVE THE FOURTH
--QUERY.
--USING CTE (COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION)

WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
D.DNAME,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.DNAME ORDER BY
D.EXPERIENCE DESC) AS RNK
FROM DOCTOR
WHERE SPECIALITY = 'HEART'
)

SELECT DNAME FROM CTE
WHERE RNK = 1

Comment: Please use the formatting tools provided. I had a moment to find out that the first two lines were not part of the query, but the introduction to your answer.